# adding additional attribute preg_replace

Tags: regex

I have a string:

```
$string = '<a href="/news/blablalba">some text</a>';
```

I need to add `target="_blank"` attribute inside  tag above and http://mysite.kz before /news/blablabla.

```
preg_replace("/<a href=\"\/(.*)\">(.*)<\/a>/iU", "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\/(.*)\">(.*)\">(.*)<\/a>", $string);
```

code above won't works. Help please!

**UPDATED**

Solved this task:

```
$match1 = preg_replace("/<a href=\"\/(.*)\">(.*)<\/a>/i", "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://nashmir.kz/$1\">$2</a>", $string);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_replace('/^<a\s+(href=")(\/news\/)/i', '<a target="_blank" $1http://mysite.kz$2')`

Rule of thumb: you only need to match what is necessary. Except in very rare cases, you **never** need to match the whole input.

Comment: @Heihachi see my edit as well: you still try and match more than necessary for the job at hand.

Comment: No, look after `<a\s+`, you try and match `h`, then `r`, then..., then a quote and then another quote. Similarly, at the end of the regex, you try and match two slashes after the `s` of `news`.

Comment: By the way, $1, $2 means values from rounded brackets in regexp?

Comment: I suppose you mean `()`. In regex language, this is called a grouping. It has two properties: it captures so that you can use backreferences (which `$1` and `$2` are), and makes the contained regex atomic wrt quantifiers such as `*`, `+`, etc.

Comment: @ridgerunner I didn't know what it do, but I deleted it, thanks for the info ;) I see we have the same references.